# Wildfly CLI "resolve-parameter-values" does not work as expected

Tags: maven, jboss, wildfly

I am using JBoss EAP 7.0.5 and I want to use internal configuration values in my standalone-ha.xml like:

```
<property name="javax.net.ssl.trustStore" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/stores/trustCA.jks"/>
```

I added this value using the wildly maven plugin 1.2.0 Alpha 5 and CLI command:

```
/system-property=javax.net.ssl.trustStore:add(value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/stores/trustCA.jks")
```

Sadly it didnt went as expected:

```
<property name="javax.net.ssl.trustStore" value="/stores/trustCA.jks"/>
```

The jboss-cli.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<!--
   WildFly Command-line Interface configuration.
-->
<jboss-cli xmlns="urn:jboss:cli:2.0">

    <default-protocol use-legacy-override="true">http-remoting</default-protocol>

    <!-- The default controller to connect to when 'connect' command is executed w/o arguments -->
    <default-controller>
        <protocol>http-remoting</protocol>
        <host>localhost</host>
        <port>9990</port>
    </default-controller>

    <!-- Example controller alias named 'Test'  
    <controllers>
        <controller name="Test">
            <protocol>http-remoting</protocol>
            <host>localhost</host>
            <port>9990</port>
        </controller>
    </controllers>
    -->    

    <validate-operation-requests>true</validate-operation-requests>

    <!-- Command and operation history log configuration -->
    <history>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <file-name>.jboss-cli-history</file-name>
        <file-dir>${user.home}</file-dir>
        <max-size>500</max-size>
    </history>

    <!-- whether to resolve system properties specified as command argument or operation parameter values
                  in the CLI VM before sending the operation requests to the controller -->
    <resolve-parameter-values>false</resolve-parameter-values>


    <!-- Whether to write info and error messages to the terminal output -->
    <silent>false</silent>

    <!-- Whether to filter out commands and attributes based on user's permissions -->
    <access-control>false</access-control>
</jboss-cli>
```

I also tried using the variable like this and it still gets resolved:

```
${jboss.server.config.dir:}
```

Am I just using it wrong or can this possibly be a CLI or maven plugin error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is not caused by Wildfly itself, but probably by the Maven Wildfly plugin. This plugin does not invoke the command line native admin interface, therefore it ignores the `<resolve-parameter-values>` value. It uses the jboss client java api and it seems to perform expression evaluation - see [CommandExecutor.java#executeCommands](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-maven-plugin/blob/8e88911ff431f2e1af246362599c3afd25150fe6/plugin/src/main/java/org/wildfly/plugin/cli/CommandExecutor.java).  If you try to execute your cli command directly via `jboss-cli.sh`, it would work as you expect i.e. the variable would not get interpolated.

Comment: It's actually cause by Maven itself. In the POM Maven will attempt to resolve the `${jboss.server.config.dir}`. It should work in a CLI script, however it looks like a bug was introduced in 1.2.0, https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFMP-79.

Comment: Checked it with 1.2.0 Alpha6. Now it works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$${jboss.server.config.dir}
```

Can someone please post a link to where this is documented? :)